# Android Browser not displaying Buttons in Honeycomb3.1

Tags: android

I have an issue with Android browser Honeycomb 3.1
I'm working on a website where I must create a button with javascript.

I went on to create a basic scritpt that is run when the html is loaded

`var innerHTML = form.innerHTML;

form += "<p>XXXXXXXXX</p>"`

I tested this in desktop browser and the paragraph is show, then I tested in android emulator and it was not working, I then verified with Opera mobile, and the paragraph is displayed correctly.

Another thing I noticed is that I can do

```
document.getElementById("html").style.backgroundColor="#FF3";
```

and in Android Browser, the background is changed.

I'm not sure why adding html is not working, before this I tried using appendChild but it also didt'n work.

I would like to know if there is a known issue for this, and if so, if there exist a workaround.